# Taking postgresql backup in php using pg_dumb

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to take the backup of postgresql database using php. If I try it in the command prompt using the following then it is working. But if I try it using exec() then an empty file is generated.Also the php script gets executed infinitely.

```
pg_dump -U postgres test > D:/backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works.

```
putenv("PGPASSWORD=postgres");
$dumpcmd = array("pg_dump", "-i", "-U", escapeshellarg("postgres"), "-F", "c", "-b", "-v", "-f", escapeshellarg("D:/backup4.sql"), escapeshellarg("test"));
exec( join(' ', $dumpcmd), $cmdout, $cmdresult );
putenv("PGPASSWORD");
if ($cmdresult != 0)
{
    # Handle error here...
    echo "error";
}
```